# HHVM - Rewrite rules for single entry point

Tags: hhvm

I'm currentrly testing HipHop virtual machine to deserve a web app. Previously, I was used to run it in a LAMP environement using this htacess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteRule ^(Templates|Ressources)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Does anyone could tell me how to configure the VirutalHost in the hhvm.hdf file in ordre to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try combination of *AllowedDirectories* and *VirtualHost*:

```
AllowedDirectories {
    * = Templates
    * = Ressources
}

VirtualHost {
    * {
        Pattern = .*
        RewriteRules {
            * {
                 pattern = ^(.*)$
                 to = index.php$1
                 qsa = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```